# Not able to go back to Loginform when i click on cancel

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to go back to the LoginForm when i click the Cancel Button present in the SignUp.js..not sure how to do that if someone can help will be much appreciated.

App.js

```
import LoginForm from "./Component/LoginForm/LoginForm";
import HomePage from "./Component/HomePage/HomePage";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
  const user = [{ username: "admin" }, { password: "admin" }];
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedInn");
    if (isUserLoggedIn === "1") {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
  }, []);

  const loginHandler = (username, password) => {
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedInn", "1");
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    localStorage.setItem("currentUsername", username);
    localStorage.setItem("currentPassword", password);
  };
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedInn");
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  };
  const onSaveDataHandler = (newData) => {
    console.log(newData);
    console.log("inside app");
  };
  const dataFormHandler = (username, password) => {
    return [
      localStorage.getItem("currentUsername"),
      localStorage.getItem("currentPassword"),
    ];
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {!isLoggedIn && (
        <LoginForm
          adminUser={user}
          onLogin={loginHandler}
          onSaveData={onSaveDataHandler}
          dataForm={dataFormHandler}
        />
      )}
      {isLoggedIn && (
        <HomePage onLogout={logoutHandler} user={dataFormHandler()} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

LoginForm.js

import styles from "./LoginForm.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import SignUp from "../SignUp/SignUp";
const LoginForm = (props) => {
  const [enteredUsername, setEnteredUsername] = useState("");
  const [enteredPassword, setEnteredPassword] = useState("");
  const [isTrue, setTrue] = useState(true);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  const onChangeHandlerUsername = (event) => {
    setEnteredUsername(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value === enteredUsername) {
      setTrue(true);
    }
  };
  const onChangeHandlerPassword = (event) => {
    setEnteredPassword(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value === enteredPassword) {
      setTrue(true);
    }
  };
  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (
      enteredUsername === props.adminUser[0].username &&
      enteredPassword === props.adminUser[1].password
    ) {
      props.onLogin(enteredUsername,enteredPassword);
      // props.dataForm(enteredUsername,enteredPassword);
    } else {
      setTrue(false);
    }
  };
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setIsClicked(true);
  };
  const sendDataToChild = (entereduserData) =>{
    const userData = {
      ...entereduserData,
      id: Math.random().toString()
    };
    props.onSaveData(userData);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {isClicked &&
      enteredUsername !== props.adminUser[0].username &&
      enteredPassword !== props.adminUser[1].password ? (
        <SignUp dataTransfer={sendDataToChild} clk={isClicked}/>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
          <h1 className={styles.blink_me}>W E L C O M E</h1>
          <div className={`${styles.box} ${!isTrue && styles.wrong}`}>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={enteredUsername}
              placeholder="Enter Username"
              className={styles.email}
              onChange={onChangeHandlerUsername}
            ></input>
            <input
              type="password"
              value={enteredPassword}
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              className={styles.email}
              onChange={onChangeHandlerPassword}
            ></input>
            <div>
              <button className={styles.btn}>Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={onClickHandler}
                type="button"
                className={styles.btn2}
              >
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#top">Forget Password</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default LoginForm;

SignUp.js

import styles from "./SignUp.module.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const SignUp = (props) => {
  const [enteredUsername, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [enteredFirstname, setFirstname] = useState("");
  const [enteredLastname, setLastname] = useState("");
  const [enteredPassword, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [isFormValid, setIsFormValid] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsFormValid(
      enteredUsername.trim().length > 0 &&
        enteredFirstname.trim().length > 0 &&
        enteredLastname.trim().length > 0 && 
        enteredPassword.trim().length>0
    );
  }, [enteredUsername, enteredFirstname, enteredLastname, enteredPassword]);

  const onUserChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  };
  const onFirstChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setFirstname(event.target.value);
  };
  const onLastChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setLastname(event.target.value);
  };
  const onPassChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };
  const onBtnSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userData = {
      username: enteredUsername,
      firstname: enteredFirstname,
      lastname: enteredLastname,
      password: enteredPassword,
    };
    props.dataTransfer(userData);
    setUsername("");
    setFirstname("");
    setLastname("");
    setPassword("");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.input}>
        <form onSubmit={onBtnSubmitHandler}>
        <h2>SignUp Page</h2>
          <label htmlFor="fname">User Name: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="uname"
            onChange={onUserChangeHandler}
            name="username"
            value={enteredUsername}
            placeholder="Your username.."
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="lname">First Name: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="fname"
            onChange={onFirstChangeHandler}
            name="firstname"
            value={enteredFirstname}
            placeholder="Your first name.."
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="lname">Last Name: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="lname"
            onChange={onLastChangeHandler}
            value={enteredLastname}
            name="lastname"
            placeholder="Your last name.."
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="lname">Password: </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="pass"
            onChange={onPassChangeHandler}
            value={enteredPassword}
            name="pass"
            placeholder="Your Password.."
          />
          <br />
          <button className={styles.btn} disabled={!isFormValid}>
            Save
          </button>
          <button className={styles.btn1} type="button">
            Cancel
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no onClick handler on cancel button

You need to pass setIsClicked prop to signup component.

Then on onClick handler of cancel button you need to set isClicked boolean with setIsClicked method

Answer (score 1):

```
<button className={styles.btn1} type="button" onClick={this.handleCancel}>
  Cancel
</button>
```

and above render in same component above render you can implement

```
handleCancel = () => {
  this.props.history.push("/loginform");
};
```

Comment: Not sure what r u saying.....tried the above code but not working.